# image border not displaying html email

Tags: html, css

I am trying to send an html email with an image border as

```
<p align="center">
    <img src="images/pic1.jpg" width="443" height="148" align="middle" 
         style="border: 1px solid grey; padding:10px;" border="1"/>
</p>
```

However, the border just does not display in any of the email clients. How can i fix this?

Comment: Maybe better to put the border inside the image as a part of the graphics, also any margins if the background allows it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest your in for a hard time using "p" tags. Tables will 100% be the way to go in this situation. I know I know, tables blow, but for email clients that use word as their html render *cough outlook cough* and ones like hotmail and gmail running html 1 (this might be a little bit of a strech but its somewhere around there), you never really know how things are going to turn out.

As for an answer to your question, try

```
display:block
```

on your image. Generally you want to put display:block on all your images as well as heights and width to insure there are no weird gaps between image slices.

Comment: `<p>`'s works in email even with outlook by way of using `Margin:8px 0;` as an example. The uppercase "M" seems to be respected.

Answer (score 5):

Main problem is Microsoft Outlook, enclosing the image in a table seems to do the job.
It's a hassle to enclose every image, but dats em breaks:

```
<p align="center">
    <table><tr><td style="border: 1px solid grey;">
    <img src="images/pic1.jpg" width="443" height="148" align="middle" 
         style="padding:10px;"/>
    </td></tr></table>
</p>
```

Comment: `<table>` is not allowed inside `<p>`

Answer (score 1):

According to this: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ border should be working properly.

I would try two things:

First add the following to the image, which will also help with Gmail rendering bugs

```
display:block;
```

And also, maybe try:

```
border-top: 1px solid gray;
border-right: 1px solid gray;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
border-left: 1px solid gray;
```

Answer (score 1):

a little bit off topic but mailchimp has a great tool for translating a normal HTML layout with seperate CSS classes into an inline CSS version

http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css

and also a great tutorial how to code HTML emails the right way

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails/

and regarding your CSS problem.

Try wrapping the image in a table cell and give the cell the border.

Unfortunately with HTML E-mails, tables are your friend, yet again.

Have fun

Answer (score -2):

try changing the color either to it's value, #808080  or it's properly spelled version 'gray'

Comment: That does not help. Same output